# www-data running command not working

Tags: command-line, sudo, php, nginx

I'm using nginx with php , and I would like to run some command with exec()
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php .

the current example work perfectly `echo exec('whoami');` but when I try with other command the output is empty.

the exec() is enabled on my php.ini and the safe mode is disabled , I also edited the sudoers `www-data  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  but `sudo -u www-data cammand` still required a password

Any solution please, thank you all

Comment: I don't think that adding a user to sudoers list means that it'll not require password. That'd be very insecure

Comment: it's just for testing , if this will work I will simply provide a specific command for the user , but it's do nothing for now :/

Comment: It does nothing because it's not possible. As I said adding a user to sudoers list means that user can use sudo but it does not mean that it'll get direct access to root.

Comment: thank you for this informations , so is their any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to do such things

Use caution: This a very dangerous way of doing things as it violates the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

This is a very vague sample

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn su
expect "Password:"
send "password\n";
interact
```

See if you can convert it to your use.

Comment: You can read their documentation to understand it properly. However, I still stand against doing it. It's better never to take this kind of risk.